Windows 11 and Asus AX3000 Edge cannot display web page but pings work
On computer with Windows 11 WiFi card Asus PCE-AX3000 is installed. User cannot display web page in web browser. Ping works. Computer is connected to wifi router or to mobile phone with hotspot. In both cases result is the same. Mobile phone or router detects one device that is connected. We can send ping to public domains. But we cannot display web page in Edge browser.

If you are trying to use the computer as  a "Web Server", it needs such software.  Common candidates are

IIS
Apache

It has nothing to do with hardware recommendations.
